# Can we specify forbidden edge constraints in Google OR Tools?

Tags: or-tools

I'm trying to solve a classic Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP). I'm using [Google OR Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp) default TSP wrapper code. I want some arcs to be forbidden, in the sense that perhaps there is no path between node 10 and node 12. In this instance, I set the value to a large number, like 10^6, but the solver still uses that arc.

I verified that this particular instance has a feasible solution, in the sense that when I run the same code twice or extend the time limit of the solver from 30s to 60s, the solver found a solution that does not use this arc.

The question I have: is there a way to specify a hard constraint that this can't be used, instead of setting the arc cost to ∞? I imagine that in a classic TSP Linear Program, a constraint can be set on the binary decision variable.

Comment: P.S. the optimal tour length is around 20000, so 10^6 definitely drives the solution to a ridiculously high cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Create a routing dimension so you can set a vehicle capacity (i.e. vehicle longest distance allowed). Thus any arc whose transit cost is above this capacity is effectively forbidden (vehicle capacity is an hard constraint).

e.g.

```py
# Add Distance constraint.
dimension_name = 'Distance'
routing.AddDimension(
  transit_callback_index, # you can reuse the same callback use in SetArcCost
  0,  # no slack
  42_000, # vehicle maximum travel distance
  True,  # start cumul to zero
  dimension_name)
```

now every arcs above 42_000 is forbidden.

2. You can remove some arcs by tweaking the `routing.NextArc()`
   e.g. to remove arc {I,J}

```py
i_index = manager.NodeToIndex(I)
j_index = manager.NodeToIndex(J)
routing.NextVar(i_index).RemoveValue(j_index)
```

note: you also have the `RemoveValues([....])` to suppress a list of outgoing arcs.